# FAHP/AHP for GIS in free software?

Tags: open-source-gis

Anyone knows a free GIS software that implements the Analytic Hierarchical Process (or its fuzzy extended version) ?

And while asking, have anyone had any experience with a commercial GIS that implements this process, if so, it would be nice to share it. Doing research, I've come to understand that IDRISI 17 implements it, ArcGIS has a [extension](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=13764) as well.

We intend to apply Fuzzy AHP to identify waste disposal areas, the hierarchy and layers are already prepared but we're still yet to find a tool to automate the calculations (weights of criterias), if we find none, we think about going the MATLAB way but I would here be keen to receive your suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at GRASS GIS, [MCDA in GRASS](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/MCDA_in_GRASS), and the addon module:

- [r.mcda.ahp](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/r.mcda.ahp.html) - generate a raster map classified with analytic hierarchy process  (AHP) for GRASS 7
- [r.mcda.ahp](https://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass6/raster/r.mcda.ahp/description.html) - idem for for GRASS 6

The modules (r.mcda.electre, r.mcda.fuzzy, r.mcda.regime, r.mcda.roughset and r.mcda.ahp) are explained in [MCDA-GIS integration: an application in GRASS GIS 6.4](http://ogrs2012.heig-vd.ch/public/ogrs2012/slides/Rocchi.pdf) (Massei G., Rocchi L., Paolotti L., Greco S., Boggia A.)

Answer (score 1):

you have an ahp function in grass

r.mcda.ahp - Generate a raster map classified with analytic hierarchy process (AHP).

I've used it with IDRISI in the past and it worked well.

Comment: Which version of IDRISI have you used ?

Comment: it was idrisi 32, and also "Andes"

Comment: Any chance Taiga has it ?

Comment: idrisi 32 was before Taiga, so I think that it should be included in Taiga too.